# Non-constant object as an argument to a function with constant parameter (C++)

Tags: c++, reference, constants, pass-by-reference

When I create a local variable `num` inside the `main()` function and pass this variable into the function `dosmth(const int& num)` that expects a reference to a constant integer, the program works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void dosmth(const int& num) { // Same address. Non-modifiable.

    cout << &num << endl; 
    
    // num++; // Compiler error
}

int main() {
    int num = 10; // Same adress. Modifiable.
    dosmth(num); 
    num++; // No compiler error.
    cout<<&num;
    return 0;
}
```

The current ISO C++ (2020) standard states in Section 9.4.3 that:

> ......
> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type
> “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>   is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is
>   reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”,
> - or has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an lvalue of type
>   “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3” (this
>   conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion
>   functions (12.4.1.6) and choosing the best one through overload
>   resolution (12.4)),
>
> then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in
> the first case and to the lvalue result of the conversion in the
> second case (or, in either case, to the appropriate base class
> subobject of the object) .........

In other words, the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue - which is a `const int`  in this case. However, I cannot understand how a locally declared variable in the `main` function (i.e. `int`) can be shared by two functions (`main` and `dosmth`) and occupy the same virtual address at the same time, while its type is different in the scope of these two functions (one is read-only, the other is not). As far as I know, passing-by-reference creates an *alias* to the actual parameter, which is not a copy but actually points to the actual variable. If the reference is bound to a `const int` according to the standard, it should now point to a `const int`, but what it points is a variable, namely `num`.

Comment: If you take a `const ref&` of some `ref`, there's no problem, as the `const ref&` will still not be modifiable (through that reference). If you have `int a = 0;`, then it's perfectly valid to do `const int& b = a;`. This comes down to the semantics of [CV-qualification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv), but overall it can help to think of "const" as a signal for "I promise not to modify", rather than requiring something that _cannot_ be modified.

Comment: What you quote doesn't say that `num` refers to `const int`, what it says it that it behaves as if it dose refer to a `const int`.  The `int` it refers to doesn't have to be `const`.

Comment: In general, you can always add `const`, it's removing it that can lead to issues.

Comment: @NathanOliver "...what it says it that it behaves AS IF it dose refer..." does this imply an abstraction that differs the case from the ordinary const expressions? Rogue gave a reasonable argument what I believe confirms my assertion.

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer Yes.  Technically it would be legal, in this exact case, to cast away the `const` from `num` and modify it.  That is because the thing `num` refers to is a non-const object and it is legal to modify a non-const object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a non-constant object

```
int num = 10; // Same adress. Modifiable.
```

So it may be changed.

```
num++; // No compiler error.
```

You passed the object to the function by constant reference. So within the function the object may not be changed.

From the C++20 Standard (9.2.9.2 The cv-qualifiers)

> 3 A pointer or **reference to a cv-qualified type need not actually
> point or refer to a cv-qualified object**, but it is treated as if it
> does; a const-qualified access path cannot be used to modify an object
> even if the object referenced is a non-const object and can be
> modified through some other access path.

For example you can write

```
int x = 10;
const int &crx = x;
int &rx = x;
```

and then

```
rx += 20;
```

But you may not write

```
crx += 20;
```

Comment: This is what I ask. How can I pass by constant reference? The thing I refer to was not originally declared as a constant after all.

Comment: That's okay, you can pass a non-constant value as a constant reference, and in the context of that function the referred-to argument cannot be modified.

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer See the quote from the C++20 Standard in the answer.

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer The type of a variable is a language abstraction, it does not actually exist on a machine level. Const checks are done by the compiler at the abstract level, while the machine simply deals with a sequence of bits contained in the CPU registers.